# Get Locale from session object

Tags: java, spring-boot, localization, internationalization

I am noob and want to make internationalization for a spring boot app. This is what I have tried but can not get it to work :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CarriersApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired WebContextHolder webContextHolder;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(CarriersApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
public RestTemplate createRestTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}


@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {

    HttpSession session = webContextHolder.getSession();
    String lang = ((Merchant) session.getAttribute( "principal" )).getLanguage();

    // the code above is an attempt to get language from session object to set the 
     // default locale 
    // ex: lang = en,fr

    SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    slr.setDefaultLocale( new Locale( lang) );
    return slr;

}

@Bean
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    lci.setParamName("lang");
    return lci;
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor( localeChangeInterceptor());
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
}
```

My question is: Is there a possibility to get the locale from 'principal' session object in this manner, when I define `localeResolver()` method?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the locale from LocaleContextHolder as folows :

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
    SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    slr.setDefaultLocale(locale);
    return slr;

}
```